# Chrome Extension load HTML page inside content page

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-api

Hey all I am trying to load an HTML page within the *content* part of the page. The HTML page is a drag and drop type of box that I want to float around the content page. This page allows the user to move the box anywhere around the area they wish.

However, I am unable to find any **good** examples of how to inject my HTML page within the content page? The HTML page does have calls to load CSS and JS as well.

I can do the following:

```
$('body').prepend(HTMLcodeHere);
```

And it does load into the content page but like I said above, I have css and js that need to also be loaded when that page loads so doing it that way would not work out.

Example of a **free floting window**:

[image]

I've found a few extension examples that have those type of **free floating** windows but either the code behind it is *packed* or I just dont plain understand how they did it.

So any help would be great!

Manifest:

```
content_scripts": [ {
      "css": [],
      "js": ["js/jquery.js"],
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "run_at": "document_start"
 }],

"permissions": [
    "background", 
    "notifications", 
    "contextMenus",
    "tabs",
    "storage",
    "unlimitedStorage",
    "activeTab",
    "<all_urls>",
    "http://*/*", 
    "bookmarks",
    "https://*/*"
 ],
"web_accessible_resources": ["img/*.*", "js/*.*", "css/*.*", "*.*", "html/*.*"]
```

And I am loading up the page like so:

```
document.getElementById('lfMn')
                .insertAdjacentHTML('afterend',
                    '<link href="chrome-extension://' + applicationID + '/css/codemirror.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />' + 
                    '<link href="chrome-extension://' + applicationID + '/js/beautify.js" type="text/javascript" />' + 
                    '<link href="chrome-extension://' + applicationID + '/js/packerStuff.js" type="text/javascript" />' +                       
                    '<script type="text/javascript">' + 
                        'window.onload = function(e){' +
                            'Modal.init();' +
                            'Modal.open();' +
                            'alert("hello");' +
                            'console.log(\'loadedhere\');' +
                        '};' +
                    '</script>' +
                    '<button type="button" id="whitespaces" name="whitespaces" onClick="Modal.open();">module</button>' +
                    '<!-- modal -->' +
                    '<div class="modal">' +
                        '<header class="modal-header">' +
                            '<h1 class="modal-header-title left">Settings Code</h1>' +         
                            '<button class="modal-header-btn2 right" id="saveCode" name="saveCode" data-tipso="Save current code">Save Code</button>' +
                            '<button class="modal-header-btn right" id="cleanCode" name="cleanCode" data-tipso="Clean current code">Clean Code</button>' +
                            '<button class="modal-header-btn3 right modal-close" id="close" name="close" data-tipso="Close Box">Close</button>' +
                            '<button class="modal-header-btn5 right" id="dockR" name="dockR" data-tipso="Dock Right"> </button>' +
                            '<button class="modal-header-btn4 right" id="dockL" name="dockL" data-tipso="Dock Left"> </button>' +
                            '<button class="modal-header-btn6 right" id="dockF" name="dockF" data-tipso="Dock Fullscreen"> </button>' +
                            '<button class="modal-header-btn7 right" id="dockN" name="dockN" data-tipso="Dock Normal"> </button>' +
                            '<button class="modal-header-btn8 right" id="searchIt" name="searchIt" data-tipso="Seach thru code">Search</button>' +
                            '<fieldset class="searchField" id="thesearch">' +
                                '<div class="input">' +
                                    '<input type="text" name="s" id="s" value="Enter your search" />' +
                                '</div>' +
                                '<input type="button" id="searchSubmit" value="" />' +
                            '</fieldset>' +
                        '</header>' +
                        '<div class="modal-body">' +
                            '<section class="modal-content">' +
                                '<!-- MAIN CODE AREA -->' +
                                '<div style="line-height: 0;" id="mainDiv">' +
                                    '<textarea id="source" rows="30" cols="160">' +
                                        'function change() {' +                             
                                            'var myNewTitle = document.getElementById(\'myTextField\').value;' +
                                            'if (myNewTitle.length == 0) {' +
                                                'alert(\'Write Some real Text please.\');' +
                                                'return;' +
                                            '}' +                                       
                                            'var title = document.getElementById(\'title\');' +
                                            'title.innerHTML = myNewTitle;' +                               
                                        '}' +
                                    '</textarea>' +
                                '</div>' +
                                '<!-- MAIN CODE AREA -->' +
                            '</section>' +
                        '</div>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '');
```

The only thing i see on the page is the "module" button. and it never executes the **alert("hello");** nor the **console.log(\'loadedhere\');** in the **window.onload = function(e){** script....

Answer (score 0):

There is no right or wrong way to do this, but your your html has to be dynamically added, so using `$('body').prepend()` is fine.

for the css and js you can use content scripts as so:

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://www.google.com/*"],
      "css": ["mystyles.css"],
      "js": ["jquery.js", "myscript.js"]
    }
  ],
```

optionally, you can use [web accessible resources](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources) to allow you to inject your css(or js) into the page like so:`$('head').append('<link href="<chrome-extension://ext id/mycssfile.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />')`.

Comment: Its telling me that **chrome-extension://fgajpnfeibefhialjchohaljbefddikc/css/main.css net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND** although it **is** there in the css/ directory. However, I am running the extension in Dev mode....

Comment: and i assume you tried writing the full paths to the web accessible resources.  Because i don't think you can format it that way.